# Getting Image From URL , Using curl in Cocos2dx C++

Tags: c++, curl, cocos2d-x

I am using curl in C++ to get an Image from a URL for a Cocos2dx Game. 
The Code is Working Fine. And using `CCImage` And `cocos2d::CCTexture2D` I create a `Sprite` and Add it on my Layer.

The Sprite is definitely getting added on the Layer, (I Know it because if i try to Add the Same Sprite It is getting crashed Stating `Child already Added` But its is no where to be found on Layer. I tried changing the BG Color, ZIndex of Sprite But the sprite is not visible.

here is the code:

```
void HelloWorld::getImageFromURL(const char* url)
{
    CURL *curl;       // CURL objects
    CURLcode res;
    MemoryStruct buffer; // memory buffer

    curl = curl_easy_init(); // init CURL library object/structure

    if(curl) {

        // set up the write to memory buffer
        // (buffer starts off empty)

        buffer.memory = NULL;
        buffer.size = 0;

        stringstream urlString;
        urlString<<url;
        // (N.B. check this URL still works in browser in case image has moved)

        CCLog("%s", urlString.str().c_str());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urlString.str().c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // tell us what is happening

        // tell libcurl where to write the image (to a dynamic memory buffer)

        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Utility::WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *) &buffer);

        // get the image from the specified URL

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        CCLog("Curl code: %i", res);

        CCImage* img = new CCImage();
        img->initWithImageData((void*)buffer.memory, (long)buffer.size, CCImage::kFmtPng);
        cocos2d::CCTexture2D* texture = new cocos2d::CCTexture2D(); //TODO:: leak
        texture->initWithImage(img);


        CCSprite* sprite = CCSprite::createWithTexture(texture, CCRectMake(0, 0, 256, 256));
        sprite->setPosition(CENTRE_OF_SCREEN);
        sprite->setContentSize(CCSize(256,256));
        sprite->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0, 0));
        this->addChild(sprite,1000,1000);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        free(buffer.memory);


    }

}
```

Any Help will be Greatly Appreciated.

Thanks a ton
W

Comment: What does `WriteMemoryCallback` look like? Since it is responsible for writing the image data to the buffer there's a chance the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the CURL code you are receiving, I got problems getting the image because of domains restrictions or because the URL wasn't from an image. I tested it from different URLs and I could deduce the problem from there. Hope this helps.